Prove: either there exists a $ j $ such that $ |x_j| > 1 $, or $ |x_j| = 1 $ for all $ j $.
Let $ f(x) = (x - x_1) \cdots (x - x_n) $ be an $ n $-degree monic irreducible polynomial with integer coefficients. Prove: either there exists a $ j $ such that $ |x_j| > 1 $, or $ |x_j| = 1 $ for all $ j $.The reality that we can find a monic irreducible polynomial f(x)=(x−x1)...(x−xn)
， |x1|>1
and x1
is real, |x_2| < 1 and x2
is real, |xj|=1
for all j>2 may help to  solve this question.

Note that from Newton's identities it follows that $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i$ is an integer to note that $\prod_{i=1}^n |x_i|\ge 1$. Now, note that either there exists a $j$ such that $|x_j|>1$ or $|x_j|\le 1$ for all $j$. In the latter case, note that it is not possible to have a $j$ such that $|x_j|<1$, so it must be that $|x_j|=1$ for all $j$.
